# Pgfmath code conflict

Tags: errors, pgfmath

I am using the following code, and it works except for the custom macro `\QuadraticEquations`.

However, it works in a stand alone file. Am I missing something obvious?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand*{\Difficulty}{10}%

\newcommand{\FracQuestion}[1]{%
    \foreach \i in {1,...,#1}{%
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\DenomDifficulty}{2*\Difficulty}%
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\Neum}{random(\Difficulty)}
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\Denom}{random(\DenomDifficulty)}
      \item $\dfrac{\Neum}{\Denom}$%
    }%
}%

\newcommand{\LinearSystem}[1]{%
    \foreach \i in {1,...,#1}{%
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\Xa}{random(\Difficulty)}%
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\Ya}{random(\Difficulty)}%
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\Za}{random(\Difficulty)}%
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\Xb}{random(\Difficulty)}%
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\Yb}{random(\Difficulty)}%
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\Zb}{random(\Difficulty)}%
      \item $\begin{cases}\begin{aligned}%
                \Xa x + \Ya y &= \Za \\%
                \Xb x + \Yb y &= \Zb \\%
              \end{aligned}\end{cases}$%
    }%
}%


\newcommand{\QuadraticEquations}[3]{%
    \foreach \i in {1,...,#1}{%
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\rootI}{random(-\Difficulty,\Difficulty)}%
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\rootII}{random(-\Difficulty,\Difficulty)}%
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\A}{1)}%
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\B}{-\A*(\rootI+\rootII)}%
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\C}{\A*\rootI*\rootII}%
      \item $\A x^2 \pgfmathprintnumber[showpos]{\B} x \pgfmathprintnumber[showpos]{\C} = 0$%
    }%
}%

\newcommand{\QuadraticEquationsEqualRoots}[1]{%
    \foreach \i in {1,...,#1}{%
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\A}{random(\Difficulty)}%
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\B}{random(\Difficulty)}%
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\C}{(\B*\B)/(4*\A)}%
      \item $\A x^2 + \B x + \C = 0$%
    }%
}%

\begin{document}
\section{Random Fractions:}
\begin{enumerate}
  \FracQuestion{3}
\end{enumerate}

\section{Random 2x2 Linear Equations:}
\begin{enumerate}
  \LinearSystem{3}
\end{enumerate}

\section{Random Quadratic Equations:}
\begin{enumerate}
    \QuadraticEquations{3}
\end{enumerate}

\section{Random Quadratic Equations (Equal Roots):}
\begin{enumerate}
  \QuadraticEquationsEqualRoots{3}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Weclome to TeX.SE! Please spend a couple minutes on reading [guide tour](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tour) and check out the tutorials on how to format your post: [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/formatting), [link](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks). As you can see, your question got downvoted because of such a poor formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Just read the error that the compiler yields. You get

```
\begin{enumerate} on input line 66 ended by \end{document}. \end{document}
```

It means that for some reason, `enumerate` environment hasn't been closed. When you look at `\QuadraticEquations`'s definition you can see that

```
\newcommand{\QuadraticEquations}[3]{%
    \foreach \i in {1,...,#1}{%
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\rootI}{random(-\Difficulty,\Difficulty)}%
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\rootII}{random(-\Difficulty,\Difficulty)}%
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\A}{1)}%
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\B}{-\A*(\rootI+\rootII)}%
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\C}{\A*\rootI*\rootII}%
      \item $\A x^2 \pgfmathprintnumber[showpos]{\B} x \pgfmathprintnumber[showpos]{\C} = 0$%
    }%
}%
```

defined the way that it requires from you 3 arguments whereas your macro needs only one, that's why `\end{enumerate}` is being swallowed and error occurs.

---

## TL;DR

Replace

```
\newcommand{\QuadraticEquations}[3]
```

with

```
\newcommand{\QuadraticEquations}[1]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but I don't know what is going on as know I am getting~ .0.0.0.0
1x2 − 1x − 72 = 0.0.0.0.0 1x2 − 1x − 56 = 0.0.0.0.0 1x2 −3x−70=0 ~  as the result

Comment: @PaulA I don't have such an issue when I compile the code. You can ask a new question and attack some screenshots of your output, but please, don't forget to read the [tour guide](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tour) and these two articles: [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/formatting), [link](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks)

Comment: Thanks and I think I have learnt how to format my queries from now on.